# How to lift function to transformed monad in haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I know with the data constructor and the run*** function,

I can lift any function to a specific MonadTrans instance.

Like this,

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad

liftF :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> MaybeT m a -> MaybeT m b
liftF f x = MaybeT $ do
       inner <- runMaybeT x
       return $ liftM f inner
```

But how can I generalize this liftF to

```
liftF :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => (a -> b) -> t m a -> t m b
```

Comment: Why not using `liftM` ? `t m` is  monad itself.

Comment: @thoferon,yes but `liftM` is not generalized either. Becuase I have to write `instance Monad (SomeMonadTrans m) where ...` before using `liftM`, I still have to know the SomeMonadTrans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @thoferon mentioned, you can just use `liftM`:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad (liftM)

liftF :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> MaybeT m a -> MaybeT m b
liftF f m = liftM f m

liftF' :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m, Monad (t m)) => (a -> b) -> t m a -> t m b
liftF' f m = liftM f m
```

(I had to add an additional Monad constraint to `liftF'`).

But why would you do this?  Check out the source code for [`MaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html) -- there's already a Monad instance:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (MaybeT m) where
    fail _ = MaybeT (return Nothing)
    return = lift . return
    x >>= f = MaybeT $ do
        v <- runMaybeT x
        case v of
            Nothing -> return Nothing
            Just y  -> runMaybeT (f y)
```

And actually, as `liftM` is the same as Functor's `fmap`:

```
instance (Functor m) => Functor (MaybeT m) where
    fmap f = mapMaybeT (fmap (fmap f))
```

You can find similar instances for all the transformers.

Is this what you are asking?  Can you provide some more concrete examples that show what you're trying to do and why, and in what way the existing Functor and Monad instances fail to meet your needs?

Comment: I am sorry for my English. What I mean is, in the case of `Monad`, as long as `SomeType` is an instance of `Monad`, we do not need to redefined `liftM`. In the case of a generic MonadTrans t, I have to define `t m` a `Monad` before using `liftM`. Is there a way to skip this step? Or to say, is there a universal `liftF` for every generic `MonadTrans` instances?

Comment: @Znatz but in the standard libraries, every data type that is an instance of `MonadTrans` is also an instance of `Monad`, so that `liftM` will work out of the box with all the transformers.

Comment: Thank you. I see now. I have to either take the step of defining my generic instance of `MonadTrans t => t m` as an instance of `Monad` or use the data constructor of my instance.